# How to test page speeds for websites hosted locally?

Tags: performance, browser, pagespeed

I need tools to test page load speeds for websites which are hosted locally on a LAN, and which are not accessible via WAN connections. In the past I was using Firefox with YSlow and Page Speed which helped me a lot, but since the latest Firefox version (in my case 39.0) YSlow is buggy and Page Speed disappeared from Firebug. 
Any new tools which can be installed to do these performance tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest Yslow from the command line if you're finding the plug in buggy. I'd also suggest Google Chrome Developer tools as an alternative to Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/)
plugin for Firefox , see the Net tab.
or
inspect element (Ctrl+shift+i for windows) , the Network tab on Google Chrome